# Can't eliminate "Confirm" button when liking

Tags: facebook-like, confirmation

I have read many q&a's and forum posts across the net including Facebook Developer forum. I have setup open graph and FB code on my  tag,  tag,  tags and installed the Facebook SDK after the  tag.

Yet, I continually have to confirm Likes and then, many times, the like does not record. Further the pictures that appear in the Confirm window seem to come from a Facebook image vault when I have set the  og:image to the be a screenshot of my site.

I have read about like-jacking, etc.

What is the trick to getting the Like button to work on a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe they are detecting your site as likejacking, you can debug the url with the Facebook URL Debugger and it will delete the cached tags from your site

Good luck

Comment: Thanks @Luis. How do I "debug the url with the Facebook URL Debugger"?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - You enter the URL for every page of your site.

Comment: Ok thanks again @Luis. I entered the home page of my site and I did not get any errors or like-jack messages. I did see that in the URL section for the Graph API, that the Facebook app id is different than what I have on my meta tag fb_app_id. Does that mean anything?